# How to fix TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range') onEdit in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Task:**

Given a google spreadsheet. There are cells in columns 16 and 17 initialized with an empty value and can be edited publicly, and there are cells in columns 5 and 6, with the initial status "no", which are associated with editable cells (they are hidden). If in a cell of the 5th and 6th columns, the value of each is "no", and the value of the public cell has already been changed, then the cell of the 16th and 17th columns must be closed for changes (if in the 5th and 6th columns, respectively, the value of the cell is "no") , only the user whose email address I have registered can change these values in these cells and delete them.

| Column 5 | Column 6 | ... | Column 16 | Column 17 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| no | no | ... | " " | (editable) |
| no | no |  | (editable) | " " |

where editable -- value in cell, " " - empty cell. If cell is not empty and in column 16 (respect column 5) and column 17 (respect column 6) and in column 5 or 6 status "no", editable cells must not be able to edit  publicly (in this case edit cell could be a people with earlier registered email) - in my example "mymail@gmail.com".

**Problem:**
I try to implement macros in GAS

```java
function onEdit(event) {
  var range = event.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  var idCol = range.getColumn();
  var idRow = range.getRow();
  var newValue = range.getValue();

  if (sheet.getName() == 'Sheet1' ) {
    if (idCol == 16 || idCol == 17) { 
      var adjacentCellCol = idCol + 5; // 6 if idCol is 16, 7 if idCol is 17
      var adjacentCell = sheet.getRange(idRow, adjacentCellCol);
      if (newValue !== "" && adjacentCell.getValue() == "нет") {
        var protection = sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol).protect();
        protection.removeEditor('anyone');
        protection.addEditor("mymail@gmail.com");
        protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        protection.setWarningOnly(false);
        Logger.log('Cell protected: ' + e.range.getA1Notation());
      }
    }

    if (idCol == 16 || idCol == 17) { 
      if (newValue >= 25) {
        var vartoday = new Date();
        sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol-6).setValue(vartoday);
      } else if (newValue === "" || newValue < 25) {
        sheet.getRange(idRow, idCol-6).setValue(idCol == 16 ? "not 1 module" : "not 2 module");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'range')
```

When testing macro control, it turns out that the cells are still available for changes and deletion, if I run it, I get an error, although I understand that, in theory, running this code from the script editor, the error is completely normal. The onEdit script to use (automatically) if changes are applied to the spreadsheet. The script saves this edit (event) and uses this event object (event) in scripts. If an observable manifestation of a feature is from an event editor, that event will not be captured (because no editing has taken place), and hence all properties of that event do not require attention. However, this script still does not work correctly.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You seem to understand why its not working, but you do it anyway.  If you run the onEdit fuction from the script editor `event` is undefined, so your script is failing at the first line.

Comment: @TheWizEd

I agree, but it doesn’t work and in fact editing a particular cell in the table, that’s the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
var adjacentCellCol = idCol + 5; // 6 if idCol is 16, 7 if idCol is 17
.
.
.
Logger.log('Cell protected: ' + e.range.getA1Notation());
```

With

```
var adjacentCellCol = idCol - 10; // 6 if idCol is 16, 7 if idCol is 17
.
.
.
Logger.log('Cell protected: ' + event.range.getA1Notation());
```

Comment: thanks for the comment, fixed it, though it's still impossible to achieve a solution to the problem

Comment: sorry it is not working